# My Drupal site hacked and showing wrong information on Google search engine results

Tags: php, drupal

My website when opens up on any normal browser; it shows everything fine but on Google search results, it shows some injected advertising stuff.

If I set up custom user-agent of "GoogleBot", then I can see all that garbage on the top and bottom of the site.

I disabled JavaScript and then reloaded to see if there is some JavaScript injection, but no change.

I also tried reloading the homepage after removing the ".htaccess" and "web.config" file on the root but no change.

I also tried purging/disabling the cache, but still of no use.

Even if I take Drupal to maintenance mode, it still shows that garbage content along with maintenance message.

Upon deep searching, I found some clues, but they are not much helpful in fixing this. Such as:

- wso9.php file on the root, that has all garbage-coding stuff that is next to unreadable, tried deleting file but still no change.
- syslog-int.php, similar garbage-coding, tried deleting, no change.
- Hundreds of imagexxx.php (e.g. image467.php) files inside this dir "/web/sites/default/files/ynyp" almost all of these files has most of the original website's rendered structure mixed with Lots of links/text to some "Same Day Payday Loans" website.
- Same as above with: "/web/sites/default/files/statistic/data-453.asp"

Any clues? Where should I find source of this? And how to make it stop?

Answer (score -1):

I understand your website has some security issue.

Talking about Drupal, you should start with the [Security review](https://www.drupal.org/project/security_review)  module

Aside:

- be sure you server is secure (hosted, VPS?)
- check your [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en&pli=1) page